# Maximum number of clues in a Sudoku game that does not produce a unique solution

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, logic, sudoku

You may have heard that last year it was proven that the smallest number of starting clues for a Sudoku game, guaranteeing a unique solution, is 17.
An example is shown below.

[image]

I am interested in the opposite:
What is the *largest* number of starting clues for a Sudoku game that *does not* guarantee a unique solution?

I have a lower bound of 63. This is if you take a solved Sudoku and delete every instance of two numbers (i.e., delete all the 1s and 2s). Alternatively, you could delete the top two rows, again yielding two different solutions for 63 starting clues.
Can you do better than 63, or is 63 is the highest?

Comment: It is a nice problem. (but your question will probably be closed down I'm afraid)

Comment: I also want to point out that I'm pretty sure that 17 thing was solved a long time ago. I remember doing a report on Sudoku in high school and that was already there. I think sudokus go way way back actually. But yes, I am curious about this question as well

Comment: 17 as a lower limit for givens was reported one, maybe two years ago. There you go : http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0749

Comment: Maybe this is a question for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Good question for math.stackexchange, but not this site.  If this gets closed and you repost on math.SE, please link to the new question in the comments :)

Comment: [Here you go, x-posted to math.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345244/maximum-number-of-clues-in-a-sudoku-game-that-does-not-produce-a-unique-solution)